# MySQL Sleep Process / Task

Tags: mysql

How much "sleep process" is considered bad for a MySQL DB instance?

I'm wondering if the high CPU load usage I see could be caused by the sleep processes.

The DB is an "db.r3.xlarge" instance in AWS.

Comment: Could you post htop OR top results?

Answer (score 0):

Sleeping processes take up virtually no resources.  I think I have seen 100, with no obvious detriment.